# jQuery HTML only runs when called manually

Tags: jquery

I have a small problem, that I could not find the solution.

I have the code below and, when my page loads, it doesn't work, but if I open "Console" and type Preenche(); it fills my page.

```
function Preenche() {
        $("#Apple").html(apple);
        $("#Windows").html(windows);
    }

    Preenche();
```

I want to understand What's happening...

Thanks!

---

Update:

I tried to use:

```
$().ready(Preenche());

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dataUltimaChave").html(dataUltimaChave);
        $("#qntChaves").html(qntChaves);
    });

    $(function () {
        Preenche();
    })
```

in the end and start of document but nothing worked. I'm using ASP.NET MVC5, don't if this matters..

I'm using jQuery: jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Comment: Where do you put it?
Maybe you should call it inside document ready listener
`$(document).ready(function() {`
    `Preenche();`
`});`

Comment: try to put the function inside `$(function(){your function here..})` and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your script is declared before the DOM elements with id 'apple' and 'windows' are even loaded. You need to wrap the function either `window.onload` or `$(document).ready()`

```
<script>
window.onload = function()  // or $(document).ready(function()
{
    function Preenche() {
        $("#Apple").html("hello");
        $("#Windows").html("world");
    }

    Preenche();
}
</script>
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/12555/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$( document ).ready()` so your code will  run once the page DOM is ready for your JavaScript code. So that's why it works when you use the console.